# Create lookup field on VF page + dynamic search based on lookup field value

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-soql, custom-controller

I have VF page, build to perform search on Case object. I am already performing search based on Case Status, Case Number.
I want to add one more search based on field "Product". Product(Master) is a lookup field on Case(Child).
So, how do I create a Product lookup field (with magnifying symbol besides it) and Add that its values in soql and perform a search?
Any help is appriciated !!
Thanks in advance.

Visualforce page:

```
apex:page controller="VF_CaseSearch" action="{!searchCase}" tabStyle="Case" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Case Details To Search">
            <apex:pageblockSection >
                <apex:inputText value="{!cas.CaseNumber}" label="Search Case Number"/>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cas.Status_Closed__c }" label="Status Closed?"/>
                <apex:inputText value="{!cas.Product__c}" label="Search Product"/>
            </apex:pageblockSection>

 <!---Search Button--> 
            <apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchCase}"/>
            </apex:pageblockButtons>
       </apex:pageBlock>
 <apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!caseList}" var="c"> 
                <apex:column value="{!c.CaseNumber}" headerValue="Case Number"/> 
               <apex:column value="{!c.Status}" headerValue="Status"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.Product__c}" headerValue="Product"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Custom Controller:

```
public with sharing class VF_CaseSearch {

  public Case cas{get;set;}
  public List<Case> caseList {get;set;}
  List<string> conditions = new List<string>();
  
    public VFC_CasesMultipleSearch(){
      cas = new Case();
  }
  
  public void searchCase(){
      if(caseList !=null && caseList.size()>0){
          caseList=null;
      }
      searchCases ();
      conditions.clear();
  }
  
  
  public Void searchCases(){
      if(caseList != null && !caseList.isEmpty()){
          caseList.clear();
      }

      //create a dynamic query for filter results
      String strQuery ='SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Product__c, Status, Status_Closed__c FROM Case';
    
      if(cas.CaseNumber !=null && cas.CaseNumber !=''){
          conditions.add('CaseNumber Like\'%' +cas.CaseNumber +'%\' ');
      }
      
       if(cas.Product__c !=null && cas.Product__c !=''){
          conditions.add('Product__r.Name Like\'%' +cas.Product__c +'%\' ');
           system.debug('Product Name' + cas.Product__c);
      }
            
       if(cas.Status_Closed__c){
          conditions.add('Status_Closed__c='+cas.Status_Closed__c);
       }else{
           conditions.add('Status_Closed__c='+ cas.Status_Closed__c);
       }
      
      if (conditions.size() > 0) {
          strQuery += '  WHERE  ' + conditions[0];
          for (Integer i = 1; i < conditions.size(); i++)
              strQuery += '  AND  ' + conditions[i];
      }
      
      caseList = Database.query(strQuery);

  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `inputText` instead of [`inputField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm)?

Comment: Hi @DavidCheng, Thanks for your response! There is actually no reason. I was unaware of inputField functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to to do this by using <apex:inputField > tag. This tag is metadata aware so it will automatically show standard lookup input with magnifying glass and all.

Simply add this
<apex:inputField value="{!cas.Product_lookup__c}" label="Search Lookup Product"/>

in your search pageblocksection and you will have to modify your search method accordingly containing the logic to add this lookup field related filter in dynamic query. It should look like below based on your existing code.

if(!String.isEmpty(cas.Product_Lookup__c)) {
conditions.add('Product_Lookup__c ='+ cas.Product_Lookup__c);
}

Comment: Thanks much @SushantN!! I did what you said and it worked. Here is the modified one:  `<apex:inputField value="{!cas.Product__c}" label="Search Product"/>`   `if(!String.isEmpty(cas.Product__c)){
          conditions.add('Product__c =\'' +cas.Product__c +'\' ');`